# Progress Web App Prompt choise problem in not chrome browsers

Tags: android, google-chrome, installation, progressive-web-apps, prompt

I try to publish a web page as as PWA app with SAMSUNG internet.
I would like to use a custom "Add to home screen" pop up. For this i have to use the following event and i like to listen to the user choice.
In Chrome the user choice does fire after the user choice...
but in SAMSUNG  internet it doesn't react to this...
... can somebody helps me with this?

Thanks

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function (e) {

   deferredPrompt = e;
   deferredPrompt.preventDefault();

   deferredPrompt.then((choice) => {
   if (choice.outcome === 'accepted') {
      console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
   } else {
      console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
   }
   // Clear the saved prompt since it can't be used again
      installPromptEvent = null;
   });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

From *caniuse* Samsung internet does not support the `beforeinstallprompt` and `appinstalled` events.

Ref: https://caniuse.com/#feat=web-app-manifest

So you won't be able to use it this way at all.

caniuse screenshot as of 2020-04-13
[image: caniuse scrot as of 2020-04-13]

Comment: there's no way to customize installation in this browsers

Comment: @DrWeb if this helped/answered your question, please upvote/accept it. It is not possible to show a popup to install it to homescreen on samsung internet. The user can do it manually with a button in the URL Bar apparently. See https://love2dev.com/pwa/add-to-homescreen/ for more info